# Origami diagram page layout: placing pictures along a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Currently origami diagrams are made using vector drawing programs (like inkscape) and then are combined using pdf tools. Now, I wondered if this process could be automatised. At least, the placing of the steps on the page (with possible symbols between) like in the following examples:

[image: Page layout]
([image courtesy](https://snkhan.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4884&start=60#p141512))

However, different layouts should be possible, such as

[image: Different page layout]
([image courtesy](https://snkhan.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4884&start=45#p121567))

---

In [External images displayed in circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24541/external-images-displayed-in-circle) one displays images in a circle using TikZ. Using a similar idea I could get one page working if I know the coordinate of where the images should be placed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
      \node at (somex, somey) {
        % uses the fact that all images are of the form 'img' + number
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{img\i} 
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, it should be able to give a list of pictures (img1, ..., imgn) and a number of images per page and then everything should be placed accordingly. Ideally, one would have environments or commands such as the following:

```
\diagrampage{<number of images on page>}{<type of path>}
\diagram{<total number of images>}{<images per page>}{<type of path>}
```

**Question:**
How can this be achieved? Any help/links/suggestions/packages are welcome. Would it be a good idea to make this into a style class? A big problem is automatically determining the coordinates of the steps.

Related: [Origami package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165717/origami-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**U*PDATE**: Without parametrizing the curve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % picture taken from www.marmots.org
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{mark four/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.02 with {\coordinate (#1-1);},
mark=at position 0.35 with {\coordinate (#1-2);},
mark=at position 0.65 with {\coordinate (#1-3);},
mark=at position 0.98 with {\coordinate (#1-4);}
}}}}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=15pt,gray!20,mark four=first] plot[smooth,tension=1.5] 
  coordinates {(6,0) (-6,4) (6,8) (0,10) (-4,9.5)};
  \foreach \X [count=\Y]in {4,...,1}
  {\node at (first-\Y){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{img-\X}};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\hspace*{-3cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=15pt,gray!20,mark four=second] plot[smooth,tension=1.5] 
  coordinates {(-6,0) (6,4) (-6,8) (0,12) (4,14)};
  \foreach \X [count=\Y]in {5,...,8}
  {\node at (second-\Y){\includegraphics[width=2cm]{img-\X}};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could also load the hobby library in order to draw the curve, but for most purposes the built in `smooth plot` may be sufficient. And you may also put the nodes with the pictures directly in `mark four` style.

It is very simple if you parametrize the curve. I constructed two examples that resemble your screenshots. And I don't have your origamis, so I just took some pictures from the marmot recovery foundation website. The strategy was to take rotated sine curves and deform the ends a bit by adding pieces that go with some positive or negative powers of the curve parameter `\x`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % picture taken from www.marmots.org
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=15pt,gray!20] plot[domain=1:4,variable=\x,samples=200]
  ({-5*sin(160*\x+180)+6/\x^2},{12*\x-0.27*\x*\x*\x+5/\x^2});
    \foreach \y [count=\x] in {4,...,1}
    { \node[label=below:img-\y] at
    ({-5*sin(160*\x+180)+6/\x^2},{12*\x-0.27*\x*\x*\x+5/\x^2}) {
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{img-\y} 
      };}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=15pt,gray!20] plot[domain=1:4,variable=\x,samples=200]
  ({5*sin(160*\x+120)-3/\x^2},{7*\x+5/\x^2});
    \foreach \x [evaluate={\y=int(4+\x)}] in {1,...,4}
    { \node[label=below:img-\y] at
    ({5*sin(160*\x+120)-3/\x^2},{7*\x+5/\x^2}) {
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{img-\y} 
      };}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Finding a parametrization of a good curve is not that easy...

Comment: Could you come up with a curve that goes on to the next pages?

Comment: @SimonMarynissen I added a more complete example, in which I also explain how I "guessed" these curves.

Comment: [`hobby`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby?lang=en) package might help.  You give it the points you want, it finds the curve...

Comment: @Thruston Do you know of such a package? Or literature concerning such curves?

Comment: @Thruston I was of course aware of the hobby library, in fact I was using it in an answer before. In my updated answer I use  `smooth plot`s in order to connect the points. Anyway, thanks for suggesting this!